# populate my data structure with thousands of real english words

Tags: java

I need to test my data structure (in java) which is like a dictionary - holds a key/value map. I would like to know how do you test your data structure? I would like to insert real words in my data structure and then find them. I am wondering if there is a way to download all the english words and then I can read that file and populate my structure. Once populated, I can perform many searches and produce some real statistics of how long does it take to search?

Comment: A good test for your `Map` would probably be to compare it to existing implementations (e.g. `HashMap`). Peter Norvig's _How to Write a Spelling Corrector_ would be a reasonable way to exercise the implementation: http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html Scroll down to find Java implementations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are indeed several open-source dictionaries for the English language, e.g. the [WordNet file](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/download/).

That said, I must insist that the English language is not a “closed” language, nor does it have *one true* official definition. As such, there is no dictionary that contains “all the English words” and such a dictionary can never exist: English words are made up all the time, and once enough people use them, the become part of the English language. Case in point: “to google.”

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/wiki/Main_Page) would be helpful.  I've used them on past CS projects.  They provide plain text files (e.g. [The Valley of Fear](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/3289/3289.txt)), which should be easy to process.  You may want to skip over the headers to avoid skewing the results.

This will let you test your dictionary by keeping e.g. a word->count mapping (e.g. `Map<String, Integer>`) of the words in the file.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on Linux, you could use the contents of `/usr/share/dict/words`; there's also [WordNet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/), an English word database.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a key-value pair you probably don't want a simple list of words, you want words to definitions or to words in other languages.

If you don't mind parsing a text file, [IDP](http://www.ilovelanguages.com/idp/IDPfiles.html) has a bunch of files for download royalty free.